# Foreign characters show up as ????? in Excel VBA 2010 after pasting from the clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

Foreign characters show up as ????? in Excel VBA 2010 after pasting from the clipboard. E.g. - if I copy `ВЫБРАТЬ ПЕРВЫЕ 100 Контрагенты.Наименование, Контрагенты.ссылка ИЗ Справочник.Контрагенты КАК Контрагенты` from this page: https://www.sql.ru/forum/1304033/comconnector-vba-funkcii-1s in Browser and then paste to VBA - I get `??????? ?????? 100 ???????????.????????????, ???????????.?????? ?? ??????????.??????????? ??? ????????????`.

But I am able to paste them to MS Words correctly, copy them again and then paste them to VBA correctly.

I found this answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78eeab51-f39e-423c-8afc-ebd218d658c3/how-to-make-vba-to-read-and-understand-characters-in-other-keyboard-language?forum=isvvba

I checked Regional and language options as prescribed there (I ensured that Language>Related Settings>Administrative Language Settings>Administrative>Change system locale is Russian).

And I ensured that the VBE font supports the foreign language.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and a sample of foreign characters you are trying to copy/paste and where are you copying them from?

Comment: In `Windows 10`, I modified `Language>Related Settings>Administrative Language Settings>Administrative>Change system locale...`. And after a mandatory reset, everything was hunky-dory. Why don't you accurately describe what you did following the guidelines in the answer?

Comment: @VBasic2008 thanks, I updated the answer. I think my case is different because I am able to type foreign symbols in VBE. I just can not paste them.

Answer (score 0):

open administrative tab
change system locate
choose your language ( Arabic )
uncheck the key use Unicode UTF - 8 for worldwide language support